# Can I use html5 cache manifest on android webview?

Tags: android, html, webview, manifest

Chrome desktop shows a message warning on console about deprecation and end of support when using a manifest appcache:

> [Deprecation] Application Cache API manifest selection is deprecated
>   and will be removed in M82, around April 2020. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6192449487634432 for more
>   details.

But there is **no** deprecation warning on the methods documentation to enable appcache on a webview: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings#setAppCacheEnabled(boolean)

Will the use of manifest cache be deprecated also on android webviews?
Is there a deadline to adapt the application?

Answer (score 0):

We should not use this anymore. It was very simple and useful but this is now a big no no.

> This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might
>   still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant
>   web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be
>   kept for compatibility purposes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache

You should consider using [Service workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers) instead.